# Local host very slow query on new posts

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

I need some help .
I have installed WAMP / WORDPRESS 4.8
Im trying to post some thousands of articles , each article into new post .
I have plenty of softwares that can do exactly what i need , the problem is that my localhost wordpress running to damn slow .
My pc can handle more than 1000 imports per second and my wordpress install can handle 1 import per 5=10 seconds ? maybe more . 
I just need to make my wordpress create new posts faster , i dont care about security problems or any other ways that makes wordpress run slow . i just need to get my job done as fast i can . 
Now , any ideas is more than welcome

PS. NO I have NOT plugins - Not single one .
The theme is twenty seventeen.

mY PC
I7-3820 3.6 GHZ
32GB RAM 1600MHZ
ASROCK EXTREME 6 2011LGA
SSD 256GB - 550MB WRITE&READ
Gigabyte GeForce GTX660 2GB OC

Answer (score 1):

This can happen because of number of reasons. Here are some common issues along with their solutions:

- **DNS Resolve Issue:**

  1. Navigate to wordpress installation directory
  2. Open `wp-config.php`
  3. Replace `define("DB_HOST", "localhost");` **with** `define("DB_HOST", "127.0.0.1");`
- **Disable IPv6 Completely:**

  [Click here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/929852/how-to-disable-ipv6-or-its-components-in-windows) for detailed guideline to disable IPv6
- **Power Plan:**

  Change Windows Power Plan (also called Power Options, in Control Panel) from the default “Balanced” (or “Power Saver”) to “**High Performance**”. “Balanced” restricts CPU Scaling. (Can increase performance upto 50%)
- **IPv6 Loopback Problem:** (cause un-necessary delay, timoeout and loopback issues)

  1. Navigate to: `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc`
  2. Open `Hosts` file in Notepad or text editor
  3. Comment out line by adding `#` in front of it e.g

     ```
     # ::1 localhost
     ```
- **Delete WAMP log and temporary files:** (run below command in CMD)

  ```
  del /S C:\WampDeveloper\Logs\*log.txt
  del /S C:\WampDeveloper\Temp\*
  ```
- **Disable CGI_MODULE**

  (**Method 1**) Right click on WAMP > Apache > Apache Modules > uncheck "cgi_module"

  (**Method 2**) Edit httpd.conf and disable the loading of the CGI module by commenting this line(adding # in front):

  ```
  #LoadModule cgi_module modules/mod_cgi.so
  ```

Hope one of the above will fix issue! :)